# how to create string wildcard in mongo::BSONObjBuilder

Tags: c++, mongodb

how can I create a mongodb queryBuilder wildcard in c++

```
mongo::BSONObjBuilder queryBuilder;
queryBuilder << "tags" << "/A/";
```

to achieve a wildcard search query, similar to the mongo shell command

db.record1.find({"tags": /A/})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a BSONObjBuilder to build an object representing a MongoDB regular expression predicate in the legacy MongoDB C++ driver, you can either:

- Use the BSONRegEx class: `queryBuilder << "tags" << mongo::BSONRegEx("A");`
- Build a "$regex" sub-object: `queryBuilder << "tags" << mongo::BSON("$regex" << "A");`

See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#regex for more information on constructing regular expression queries in MongoDB.

Note also that this question concerns the legacy MongoDB C++ driver, which is no longer recommended for new applications that are C++11-compatible.  If you are building a new application written for C++11 or a newer version of the standard, you may want to consider using mongocxx instead, which is the new MongoDB C++ Driver.  See "Driver status by family and version" at http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-cxx-driver/ and other links on that page for more information about mongocxx.

Comment: Thanks for info on this driver being obsolete. I'm maintaining existing software, a rewrite isn't practical.